# Android linearlayout orientation arrow position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-orientation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linhaCliente"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/pedidos_shape"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:layout_weight="0.28">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/numeroPedido"
                            android:text="123456 "
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/pedidos_cinza"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/pedidoID"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:columnCount="2"
                        android:layout_weight="0.28"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp">


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="19/10/2014 às 14:30"
                            android:id="@+id/data_criado"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/pedidos_cinza"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textIsSelectable="false"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:layout_weight="0.20"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="R$ 16.450,00 "
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/pedido_preco"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize2"
                            android:id="@+id/valorPedido"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="(Condição: "
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/pedido_preco"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize2"
                            android:id="@+id/condicao" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="2x "
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/pedido_preco"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize2"
                            android:id="@+id/condicaoPedido" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ViewEndereco"
            android:layout_height="8dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dot"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/statusPedido"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textColor="@color/pedidos_cinza"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above xml code gives me that result:

[image]

I need to add an arrow like the following image:

[image]

The problem is that I can't get that arrow to be aligned as it was suppose to be, either I put it aligned with the date or with the price, but I need it to be independent, exactly like the image above.

Comment: i would suggest you to first split the 1st layout vertically into two in the ratio, for eg 80:20 or so..then split the 1st vertical layout into two horizontal layouts.then add the arrow image to the 2nd vertical layout..try it..

Comment: why don't you use relative layout? why this much nested linearlayout?

Comment: You can't do what in your current setup because of the use of LinearLayout. You should revise your layout, your view hierarchy is 7 levels deep for a layout that should be at most 3 levels deep.

Comment: @Lal I didn't understand, I'm very new to android development, could you kindly give me more details on how can I achieve that? thank you

Comment: you can divide the layout as specified [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23615754/3168859)

Answer (score 0):

I manage that doing this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/linhaCliente"
    android:clickable="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/pedidos_shape"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout9">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/numeroPedido"
                        android:text="123456 "
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/pedidos_cinza"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="19/10/2014 às 14:30"
                        android:id="@+id/data_criado"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/pedidos_cinza"
                        android:textSize="15dp"


                        android:gravity="right" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/pedidoID"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout10" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="R$ 16.450,00 "
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/pedido_preco"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize2"
                        android:id="@+id/valorPedido"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="(Condição: "
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/pedido_preco"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize2"
                        android:id="@+id/condicao" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2x "
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/pedido_preco"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize2"
                        android:id="@+id/condicaoPedido" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ViewEndereco"
            android:layout_height="8dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/dot"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/statusPedido"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textColor="@color/pedidos_cinza"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```